# NativeScript / iOS Labels not fully shown in last StackLayout

Tags: ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

As you can see in the image I have a situation where the labels of the last stacklayout are partly shown. The red lines should also be squares with a number.

Strange enough the green line in the image is the bottomBorder of the StackLayout containing the labels and it looks like the space is there.

I made a [playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=AljEZ0&v=9) project which contains the situation.
This happens only on iOS and not even all iOS versions, I know of 12.4.1.

[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction or maybe even give me the solution to this problem?

Comment: Issue doesn't seem to be reproduced on iOS v13.x. Did you try setting explicit height on label, see if that solves the problem on v12.4.

Comment: When I give the StackLayout as well as the Labels inside the StackLayout a height of 150 it looks somewhat better. But still not as wanted. The first StackLayout with labels is positioned directly against the green borderBottom, where the second StackLayout has some distance.

Besides that, it doesn't feel right if setting the height is the solution.